# Provide a sorted subset of data frame for each group which certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi My data frame looks like this

```
A   B    Timestamp

1  some text  8/13/2018

1  some text 12/13/2018

2  some text 7/13/2018

1  some text 9/13/2018

2  other text Boom   12/13/2018

1  some text Boom   11/13/2018
```

I have to group the data frame on A and sort each group using timestamp. Now,  I want to filter each group in such a way that the resulting dataframe has values before "Boom" Happened.
I want my resultant dataframe to be like this.

```
A   B    Timestamp

1  some text 8/13/2018

1  some text 9/13/2018

2  some text 7/13/2018
```

I tried

```
temp1=df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["Timestamp"], ascending 
= True)).reset_index(drop=True)
temp1.groupby('A').apply(lambda 
x:x.loc[:x[x['B'].str.contains("Boom")].index[0]])
```

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
Any help please? 
Thanks

In short:I want to remove all the records that happened after "Boom" for each category.

Comment: Are the strings consistent enough to differentiate by string length alone?

Comment: Unfortunately no.There is a huge difference in the string lengths. The only way to differentiate is to look for that specific sub string.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda s: s[s.Timestamp < s[s.B.str.contains('Boom')].Timestamp.max()].sort_values('Timestamp', ascending=True))

        A   B           Timestamp
A               
1   0   1   some text   2018-08-13
    3   1   some text   2018-09-13
2   2   2   some text   2018-07-13
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super happy with this, but here is a solution

```
A = [1,1,2,1,2,1]
B= 'text text text text boom boom'.split()
T = pd.to_datetime(['2018-08-13','2018-12-13','2018-07-13','2018-09-13','2018-12-13','2018-11-13'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'B':B, 'Timestamp':T})


#Here is the solution
frames = []
for name, frame in df.sort_values(['A','Timestamp']).groupby('A'):

    ix = frame.B=='boom'

    frames.append(frame.loc[:ix.argmax(),:])

before_boom = pd.concat(frames).query('B != "boom"')
```

Output:

```
    A   B   Timestamp
    1   text    2018-08-13
    1   text    2018-09-13
    2   text    2018-07-13
```

EDIT:

I like this better

```
to_join = df[df.B=='boom'].groupby(['A','B']).Timestamp.min().reset_index()

new_df=df.merge(to_join, on = 'A', suffixes=['','_y'])

new_df.loc[new_df.Timestamp<new_df.Timestamp_y,['A','B','Timestamp']]
```

Comment: Thanks.It's working great for a single string. In my case I have to find the "Boom" from a long string, so  ==  operator is not working for me.

Comment: replace the `df.B=='boom'`  with `df.B.str.contains('boom')`

Comment: It's working like a charm! Thank you so much for you time.I really appreciate your help.